# Rounding to the next upper (or lower) 0.1

Tags: programming

I'm reading from a temperature sensor. I get float values with 2 decimals. I want to round them to nearest 0.1.

This is my sketch:

```c
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  float temperature = 21.81;
  float rounded_temperature = round(temperature * 10) / 10.0;
  Serial.print("21.81 ->");
  Serial.println(rounded_temperature);
  delay(1000);

  temperature = 21.79;
  rounded_temperature = round(temperature * 10) / 10.0;
  Serial.print("21.79 ->");
  Serial.println(rounded_temperature);
  delay(1000);

  temperature = 21.77;
  rounded_temperature = round(temperature * 10) / 10.0;
  Serial.print("21.77 ->");
  Serial.println(rounded_temperature);
  delay(1000);

  temperature = 21.70;
  rounded_temperature = round(temperature * 10) / 10.0;
  Serial.print("21.70 ->");
  Serial.println(rounded_temperature);
  delay(1000);
}
```

This is the output:

```
21.81 ->21.85
21.79 ->21.75
21.77 ->21.75
21.70 ->21.75
```

And this is the output I would... Rounded to "0" and not "5".

```
21.81 ->21.80
21.79 ->21.80
21.77 ->21.80
21.70 ->21.70
```

Comment: temperature could be also negative

Comment: this is not an arduino question ... it is a general programming question

Comment: @jsotola OP is using the round function, which is [part of the Arduino library](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/6ec80154cd2ca52bce443afbbed8a1ad44d049cb/cores/arduino/Arduino.h#L96).

Answer (score 3):

Using roundf() function:

float rounded_temperature = roundf(temperature * 10) / 10;

Answer (score 1):

`float` variables do not have a number of decimal places. They are merely an approximation anyway. Instead it's when you *print* that you decide how many decimals to display.

```cpp
Serial.println(temperature, 1); // Print with 1 decimal place
```

Or to put it into a string:

```cpp
char buf[8]; // Room for 7 characters plus NULL terminator
float val=23.81;

dtostrf(val, -7, 1, buf); // 7 characters with 1 decimal place and left aligned (negative width)
```

Comment: mmm... My trouble is that  I send that data via MQTT to HomeAssistant. I want to send them as "my format" and not with the .50

Comment: Then format it into a string and send that. Use `dtostrf` to format a `char[]`.

Comment: Isn't there a native function to round to .x0 instead of .50 ?

Comment: @sineverba Even if you do "round" the float chances are it won't be rounded. Like I said - floats are only an approximation. The only way to fix it to a specific number of digits is to change it to a different format - such as text. With `dtostrf()`.

Answer (score 1):

I often store the floating point data that I get from a sensor in integer to preserve the decimal precision that I want by multiple it by 10 before casting it into an integer. It is easier and more efficient (compare to string or float) to send over to another system. This is also how many sensors representing and store the floating data (e.g. TMP275) as well.

To achieve what you want, here is what I would do:

```
#include <math.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  float i=21.81;
  float j=21.79;
  float k=21.77;
  float p=21.70;

  // convert to integers
  int l = (int) round(i*10);  // 218
  int m = (int) round(j*10);  // 218
  int n = (int) round(k*10);  // 218
  int o = (int) round(p*10);  // 217

  // Convert back to actual floating point for display
  Serial.println((float)l/10);  //21.80
  Serial.println((float)m/10);  //21.80
  Serial.println((float)n/10);  //21.80
  Serial.println((float)o/10);  //21.70
}
```

Comment: Ok.... but 21.81 rounded is 21.80, not 21.90...

Comment: I change it to use `round()` instead of `ceil()`.